# Android - How to trigger a Broadcast Receiver to call its onReceive() method?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-broadcast

I have scheduled alarm for my application.

I have implemented broadcast receiver to be triggered once the alarm time reaches.

How to manually call broadcast receiver to execute the code inside of onReceive method without replicating the code twice.

I thought of having the code in utility singleton call and call that method by having util class instance from anywhere.

But is that any other way to call that onReceive method directly or else broadcast intent problematically.

> android:exported="false" //Additional parameter of receiver when
>   defining in manifest file.

Another question is what is that exported parameter means. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**1.** The way to launch a `BroadcastReceiver` manually is by calling

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.myapp.mycustomaction");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

where `"com.myapp.mycustomaction"` is the action specified for your `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest. This can be called from an `Activity` or a `Service`.

**2.** It is known that Android allows applications to use components of other applications. In this way, `Activity`s, `Service`s, `BroadcastReceiver`s and `ContentProvider`s of my application can be started by external applications, provided that the attribute `android:exported = true` is set in the manifest. If it is set to `android:exported = false`, then this component cannot be started by an external application. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html).

Comment: can you add the intent-filter definition? OP may be have been calling it explicitly so far

Comment: Thanks to Zygotelnit. Yes I was able to call it.

Comment: I am not fining related question with this searching word, Can u please up-vote my question to help others while searching. I have edited my question. Can nu please clarify the remaining.

Comment: Yes ZygoteInit accepted as correct answer. Can u please up-vote my question to help others.

Comment: or `Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), xClass.class);`

Answer (score 13):

Here is a more type-safe solution:

- `AndroidManifest.xml`:

  ```
  <receiver android:name=".CustomBroadcastReceiver" />
  ```
- `CustomBroadcastReceiver.java`

  ```
  public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
      {
          // do work
      }
  }
  ```
- `*.java`

  ```
  Intent i = new Intent(context, CustomBroadcastReceiver.class);
  context.sendBroadcast(i);
  ```

Answer (score 7):

You need to mention the `action` which is required to be filter by Android OS to notify you.
i.e.:
inside manifest file,

```
<receiver
android:name="com.example.MyReceiver"
android:enabled="true" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.alarm.notifier" />//this should be unique string as action
</intent-filter>
```

and

whenever you want to call broadcast receiver's onReceive method,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.alarm.notifier");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to manually call broadcast receiver to execute the code inside of
>   onReceive method without replicating the code twice.

Fire `BroadcastReceiver` using `sendBroadcast` same action which added in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CUSTOM_ACTION_STRING);
// Add data in Intent using intent.putExtra if any required to pass 
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

> what is that android:exported parameter means

As in [android:exported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#exported) doc  : *Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and "false" if not*

Means if:

**android:exported=true:**  other application also able to fire this broadcast receiver  using action

**android:exported=false:**  other application not able to fire this broadcast receiver using action