# Application crashes after turns on the device - android

Tags: android, crash

After i turn on my phone, my app crashes and does not open after that.
It just crashed although it is not open.

I don't know what the error because it appears after i turn on my phone and the logcat cannot monitor the phone and i don't see any error.

Receivers:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".ActionReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: So errors have a gender now? At least show us the relevant code?

Comment: Turn on = reboot or unlock?

Comment: HHA sorry as you can see english is not my mother tongue...I can't show the code- and i think you know why. And which activity you want?and @MasterGaurav - reboot and unlock

Comment: What do you mean by "turn on"? Do you mean reboot the device? or do you mean unlock?

Comment: Normally, I would flag a question like this as "unsalvageable". But maybe there is just some miscommunication based on language (English). The problem with your question is: If you don't provide enough _specific_ information, nobody can help you.

Comment: all know that I do not know english :( and what kind of information you need?The main Activity? what ?and please if i am doing mistakes ,ignore.

Comment: Show your `BroadCastReciever` that fires at phone start if you have one.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806342/pendingintent-cause-error)

Comment: Is it the same question?

Comment: @KNeerajLal you are right, the problem was the Receivers , Thank you all .

Comment: @KNeerajLal the problem is not the Receivers :( i dont know what to do...application crash and i dont have logcat...if you need more information just say

Comment: Any changes in code?

Comment: @KNeerajLal   Of coure was changes in code but in the manifest i didn't see any changes and i dont know what the problem...

Comment: It may be crashing because of the code changes. Did u try hardwork's answer?

Comment: yes i tried but it is help just for last alarm(for one alarm) and i have some alarm-not "final number" it can change by the user...and i cannot use database or SharedPreferences because i dont know which record in the database is the correct and same in SP...

Comment: @KNeerajLal you dont have any idea?

Comment: I need to have a look. i got your concept.

Comment: @KNeerajLal excuse me for saying this but i need to ask you if you any idea for what to do cause i work on this project a lot of time ,i approach to the end and this error stuck me.

Comment: Sorry i was out of town for two days.

You should store your alarms in database. When the phone starts you need to set the alarm again. This is the basic logic.

Comment: @KNeerajLal i have database for my alarms but how can i set the database  when my phone starts?

Comment: In you `ActionReceiver` class fetch everything from db and set the alarms one by one in a loop.

Comment: @KNeerajLal so because i dont do it i get error when i start my device??? Even i dont start my broadcast??

Comment: The easiest way is is to trigger that broadcast and see what is going wrong. hardwork's answer describes how to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671029/android-how-to-trigger-a-broadcast-receiver-to-call-its-onreceive-method

Comment: May i know what the issue was?